# String getChars() method confusion

Tags: java, ocpjp

I am reading from K&B about Strings. For some extra know how, i was reading tutorial from Oracle. I am copying the source code from Oracle.

```
public class StringDemo {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        String palindrome = "Dot saw I was Tod";  
        int len = palindrome.length();  
        char[] tempCharArray = new char[len];  
        char[] charArray = new char[len];  

        // put original string in an   
        // array of chars  
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {  
            tempCharArray[i] =   
                palindrome.charAt(i);  
        }   

        // reverse array of chars  
        for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {  
            charArray[j] =  
                tempCharArray[len - 1 - j];  
        }  

        String reversePalindrome =  
            new String(charArray);  
        System.out.println(reversePalindrome);  

        //Testing getChars method //1  
        palindrome.getChars(0, len, tempCharArray, 1);  
        String tempString = new String(tempCharArray);  
        System.out.println(tempString);  
    }  
}
```

I added point-1 in source code. I was understaning getChars method. When i run it, this program give me ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Here is what i read in String docs.

> public void getChars(int srcBegin,  int srcEnd,  char[] dst,  int
>   dstBegin)
>
> Throws:  IndexOutOfBoundsException - If any of the following is true: 
>   srcBegin is negative.  srcBegin is greater than srcEnd  srcEnd is
>   greater than the length of this string  dstBegin is negative 
>   dstBegin+(srcEnd-srcBegin) is larger than dst.length

What is the destBegin? What offset, the documentation is talking about. 1 is a valid offset in destination array. Please help me solve this confusion.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add to your question the source and destination strings? That might help us clarify why it's going out of bounds.

Comment: not sure what is the question... 1 is a valid offset

Comment: @JasonD source string is included in the program.

Comment: Missed that, it's in palindrome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getChars(int,%20int,%20char[],%20int))

> the characters are copied into the subarray of dst starting at index
>   dstBegin and ending at index:
>
> ```
>  dstbegin + (srcEnd-srcBegin) - 1
> ```

so in you case is

> 1 + (len - 0) -1 = len

note that this is the **end Index** - so your end index is `len` but in your array the last index is `len -1`

Comment: it means that, length of destination is automatically calculated at runtime using the formula dstbegin + (srcEnd-srcBegin) - 1, by the JVM itself. Is that true?

Comment: why does it matter when he calculated it ? maybe it doesn't care and just simply try to write

Answer (score 1):

You get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you have run out of room in the destination array `tempCharArray`, which is of length `len`.  To copy the array, have `getChars` start in the destination array at the beginning of the array, at index `0`.

```
palindrome.getChars(0, len, tempCharArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

tempCHarArray is of same length as that of palindrome. You are trying to copy the palindrome array starting at index 1. Try this and rerun or start index at 0 ->

```
char[] tempCharArray = new char[len + 1];
```